# What is causing this double scrollbar/whitespace?

Tags: css, wordpress, scrollbar, whitespace

I've got a strange problem with Chrome, Firefox and obviously IE. 
I'm building a WordPress theme for my portfolio site/blog and everything has been okay, up until today when I viewed the site in chrome and suddenly there was a large white bar at the bottom of the page, when the page is viewed in Firefox/IE it shows a double sidebar. 
here is the page http://iamdannygreen.com/?p=5
Please excuse the ugly header in firefox, havent yet bug fixed all browsers. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fix your header and remove `overflow-x: hidden` from body and it'll work just fine.

By fix your header, I mean, what is this...?

```
margin-left:-1000px;
padding-left:1000px;
padding-right:1000px;
margin-right:1000px;
```

If you want the header background to span the width of the window, move it outside of `#wrapper` and put another wrapper inside for the content (so the content stays centered).

```
<div id="header">
    <div class="wrap">content here</div>
</div>
<div class="wrap" id="content"> body stuff here </div>

.wrap {
  width: 500px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
  background-color: #CCC;
}

#content {
  background-color:#FFF;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://cssdesk.com/NcwDW).

Comment: Thanks for your comprehensive answer and demo, really helped. Thanks :